# Postgres running slow after indexing finished

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

My postgres was running really slow lately, an aggregation for a month it usually ended up taking more than 1 minute (to be more exact the last one took 7 mins and 23 secs).

Last friday i recreated the servers (master and replica) and reimported the database.

First thing I noticed is that from 133gb now the database is 42gb (the actual data is around 12gb, i guess the rest are the indexes).

Everything was fast as hell for a day, after that the indexing finished (26gb on indexes) and now I'm back to square 1.

A count on ~5 million rows takes 3 mins 42 secs.

Made the autovacuum more aggressive and it looks like it's doing it's job now but the DB is still slow.

I am using the db for an API so it's constantly growing. Atm i have 2 tables one that has around 5 mil rows and the other 28 mil.

So if the master has a lot of activity and let's say that i'm expecting some performance loss, i don't expect it from the replica.

What's curios is that after a restart it's really fast for an hour or so.

Also another thing that i noticed was that on every query I do the IO is 100% while the memory and cpu are almost not used at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Same database on a smaller machine works like a charm.
Same queries, same indexes.
The only difference is the traffic, not writing or updating that much.

Also i forgot to mention one thing, one of my indexes is clustered.

The live machine is a 5 core with 64gb and 3k IO.
The test machine is a 2 core with 4gb and an SSD.

**Update**

Found my issue.
Apparently the autovacuum can't get a lock and by the time it gets it the dead tuples increased.

Made the autovacuum more aggresive for now and deleted a bunch of unused indexes.

Still don't know how to fix the lock issue tho.

**Update**

Looks like something is increasing the estimated row count.
Since my last update here the row count increased by 2 mil.
I guess that by tomorrow the row count will be again around 12 mil and the count will be slow as hell again.

Could this be related to autovacuum?

**Update**
Well found my issue.
Looks like postgres is losing a lot of speed on a write intensive database.
Had a column that was used as a flag and updated a lot of times per day.
Everything looks really good after the flag and update was removed.

Any clue on how to fix this issue on a write intensive table?

Comment: Can you post the execution plans?

Comment: For the count? You are referring to an explain, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, an explain.

Comment: explain analyze select count(id) from subscriptions.events . http://pastebin.com/jYV9e9aK

Answer (score 0):

May be the following pointers help:

- Are you really sure you want to do a 5mil row Aggregation for an API? Everytime ? Can't you split the data into chunks such that only a small number of chunks actually get most of the new rows (and so the aggregation of all the previous chunks can be reused for the next Query)? Time is one such measure, serial numbers could be another, etc. If so, partitioning the data is an obvious solution you should investigate, it really has a good chance of giving you sub-second query times (assuming you store aggregations for previous chunks smartly).
- A hunch about that first hour magic is that although this data fits RAM, concurrent querying pushes that data-set out and then its purely disk I/O... and in that case, CPU / RAM being idle isn't a surprise.
- Finally, I think this setup is asking for a re-design where there is only so much you could do with a single SQL, and in that expecting sub-second Query times for data that is not within RAM for a 5mil data-set is probably being too optimistic!

(Nonetheless, do post your findings, if possible)

Comment: The aggregation is based on time, the total amount in the database is 5 mil but for a month it shouldn't be more than 10-20k from the first table and around 60k from the second. Also it's done in a view.

Comment: In that case, is it not possible to store aggregates of previous months in a materialized view (supported by 9.3) and aggregate just the last few (1 or 2) months and finally do a UNION ALL? That should make this 'much' faster.... and If that works.. have a monthly cron that updates the materialized view for the month that just went by.

Comment: I think we are going to far from the problem. I will update the main post with more explanations about the view and how i'm generating the stats later today or tomorrow. What I want to know is why is this performance loss happening and why is it this harsh. I mean a count on 5 mil rows took under 1 second and 24 hrs later 7 mins. This shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Sure. That'd help also, an EXPLAIN ANALYSE would confirm the other assumption I mentioned earlier that concurrent transactions are driving the initially cached table data out of RAM and causing a lot of disk I/O.